# Best recommended form validation lib for Meteor

Tags: validation, meteor

What is the best recommended form validation library for Meteor , I have had look at the following

1. Mesosphere
2. AutoForm
3. jqBootstrapValidation

But I am not sure which one to go with? I want to go with the one that may become part of the meteor core offering eventually. Also I need to do some custom handling for some of the controls.

Comment: I am not sure how this is off topic , I am mainly trying to query the meteor community on the best recommended form validation library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently using Autoform / Collections2 / Simple-Schema. It's phenomenal and the validation comes straight from the database schema that you set that is run on both the client and the server.

If you have a firstName key in your DB and the type is set to String in your schema, for example, the form will only validate string entries. And it does so reactively on the front end. And it doesn't allow insert operations of any kind if it doesn't match the schema.

It's like finally, direct server-side validations are available directly from the front end. No need to have a set of client side validations and another set of server side validations.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Meteor roadmap](https://trello.com/b/hjBDflxp/meteor-roadmap), the forms framework will not be part of the core.

So pick whatever validation library that suits your needs the best.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any experience working on any of the form-validation library? If so which ones do you suggest I try?